# Compilation errors when dealing with C# script using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am embedding a C# script engine into my application using Roslyn and so far, I can execute code with no issues. I can for example execute the following code:

```
using System;
var str = "Hello Roslyn";
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

I am facing compilation issues when building my syntax tree out the code snippet above. The compiler complains about statements directly embedded into the main namespace which makes sense when writing a normal C# program but not in my case as I am going the script way.

**Question:**
Is there a way to build an error free syntax tree out of a C# script?

**EDIT**
Here is the code I am using to build the syntax tree.

```
SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(context.SourceCode);
Compilation compilation = Compilation.Create("CSharp", syntaxTrees: new[] {tree}, references: references);
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you are currently using to build the syntax tree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify that you're parsing script code instead of regular code:

```
SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(source, options: new ParseOptions(kind: SourceCodeKind.Script));
```

Comment: Man I wish I could give you a +100! I have been looking for this for weeks!!! Thank you very much.